# Why is Turbo not honoring link_to method: :post?

Tags: turbo, ruby-on-rails-7

For a long time, Rails has provided a `method: :post` option in the `link_to` helper: when the option was given, Rails would intercept the click and issue a POST request, instead of the default GET request.

However, for some unknown reason, this is not working in Rails 7: despite adding `method: :post` to my `link_to` helper, Rails sends a GET request (not a POST request). I thought Turbo was supposed to take care of it, but it does not seem to be happening.

This is what you can do to reproduce, very simple steps:

```
$ rails new example_app
$ bin/rails g scaffold Book title
$ bin/rails db:create && bin/rails db:migrate
$ echo "<%= link_to "New book", new_book_path, method: :post %>" >> app/views/books/index.html.erb
$ bin/rails s
```

Now visit `localhost:3000/books` from your web browser, and click on the *second* "New book" link. I would expect getting an error (after all, I did not configure the proper POST route) but, unfortunately, Rails isues a GET request - and not a POST request, as it should have:

```
Started GET "/books/new" for ::1 at 2021-12-27 17:40:43 +0100
Processing by BooksController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered books/_form.html.erb (Duration: 9.1ms | Allocations: 5216)
  Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 10.2ms | Allocations: 5594)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 12.9ms | Allocations: 7759)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 13.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms | Allocations: 12404)
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't Turbo intercept the link, and, as Rails UJS did in the past, send a POST request?

Answer (score 14):

It seems to me that the Rails 7 docs have not been updated for Turbo and the missing UJS library. Even though the [link_to documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) clearly states that `link_to(..., ..., method: :post)` should work, it clearly does not.

Diving into Turbo's documentation, there is a section called [Performing Visits With a Different Method](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#performing-visits-with-a-different-method) where it says to use `link_to ..., ..., data: { 'turbo-method' => :post }`, which DOES work.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue, but I fixed it differently than [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504229/299774):

Pinned the @rails/ujs

```
$ bin/importmap pin @rails/ujs
```

and then in application.js added:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
Rails.start()
```

And `link_to "...", "...", method: :delete` started working for me.

Consider this solution when you have a legacy app with a bunch of `method:`  links and you don't want to change them to `turbo-method:`

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo Serrano‘s answer works for POST. However, if `turbo-method` is set `:delete`, and `redirect_to` is used in the destroy action, after the 302 redirection, it will trigger the `destroy` action on the resource which is redirected to.

`button_to` does not have this problem.

I am using rails 7.0.1. There is an open issue https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/259 .

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue in ruby `3.04`, `rails 7`. The `post` method was not honoured and was intercepted as an `get` request. Using a quick fix for now by changing link_to to an button.

```
<%= button_to "Logout", :logout, method: :post %>
```